# Does adding extraneous tables in a WITH clauses slow down a query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-performance

I have a (possibly) basic question about how Postgres executes queries containing `WITH` clauses. I'm wondering whether including extraneous tables in a `WITH` clause actually slows down the query. That is, if the "temporary" table created in a `WITH` clause is never called outside of a `WITH` clause, is that "temporary" table actually created?

In the first example, I am joining two "temporary" tables created using `WITH` clauses:

```
--Example 1
WITH temp1 as (
SELECT * from table_1
),
temp2 as (
select * from table_2
)
select * 
from temp1
join temp2;
```

In the second example, I'm doing the exact same query except there is an extraneous table "temp3" created in the `WITH` clause.

```
--Example 2
WITH temp1 as (
SELECT * from table_1
),
temp2 as (
select * from table_2
),
temp3 as (
select * from table_3
)
select * 
from temp1
join temp2;
```

Is there any performance difference between these two queries? If `table_3` is a huge table, will this slow down the query in example 2 vs. example 1? If not, why not?

It seems like it **does not** affect the query time. I'm still curious as to why, though ...

Comment: Since `psql` is the name of the default command line terminal, it's better to stick to `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` - or `pg` where you need it extra short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Explain to show how the query optimizer will handle your query.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html

In the case above PSQL should see that temp3 is not used and not include it.

using your example above on one my dbs.

```
explain with temp1 as (select * from cidrs), temp2 as (select * from contacts), temp3 as ( select * from accounts )  select * from temp1 join temp2 on temp1.id = temp2.id;
                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=22.15..25.44 rows=20 width=4174)
   Hash Cond: (temp1.id = temp2.id)
   CTE temp1
     ->  Seq Scan on cidrs  (cost=0.00..11.30 rows=130 width=588)
   CTE temp2
     ->  Seq Scan on contacts  (cost=0.00..10.20 rows=20 width=3586)
   ->  CTE Scan on temp1  (cost=0.00..2.60 rows=130 width=588)
   ->  Hash  (cost=0.40..0.40 rows=20 width=3586)
         ->  CTE Scan on temp2  (cost=0.00..0.40 rows=20 width=3586)
(9 rows)
```

you will notice no mention of temp3.  In answering your edit, about why it doesn't affect query time,  the optimizer is smart enough to see that it isn't used and doesn't bother computing it. Hence the reason it is an optimizer.

Comment: It will however affect planning time, which is normally a tiny fraction of all processing time. In a test with 500k rows and 10 iterations I got temp3 query 0.5% slower.

Answer (score 6):

You got the main answer [from @Doon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20843104/939860) already.

Since you are interested in performance, note that subqueries are typically faster than [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) *in most cases*. Common Table Expressions (WITH queries) pose as *optimization barriers*. Read [this thread on pgsql-performance](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15381.1353446809@sss.pgh.pa.us) for details.

Use CTEs ...

- .. if a subquery is used multiple places, to avoid repeated execution.
- .. to keep the optimizer from trying to combine subquery and main query for some reason (performance, avoid influence on side effects from functions).
- .. to partition complex queries (readability, maintainability)
- .. for RECURSIVE queries.

Comment: Just to add that this is specifically an issue related to the implementation of CTEs in PostgreSQL, and does not apply to Oracle, for example.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Right, this is specific to Postgres, but it's considered to be a *feature* by the developers, not an issue. And I tend to agree. This, also, is discussed in the linked thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using the WITH clause because I'm building very complex queries, and I wanted to make sure that I wasn't affecting performance unnecessarily.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter pgsql-hackers thinks it's a feature. I think it's a really frustrating wart that's being sugar-coated as a feature, and we're going to hugely regret making that optimisation fence behaviour a documented, consistent part of the system. `OFFSET 0` is at least not going to get used for anything else.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Well, I agree. I like the choice between subqueries and the current implementation of CTEs. But an explicit form would be preferrable. Something like `WITH MATERIALIZED query_name AS ...`, to distinguish from CTEs without optimization barrier. Then we could actually choose one of three different forms of subqueries. Sounds like a lot of work to implement that, though. And a painful transition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Initially it'd just be a noiseword to say "I intend this barrier". So things don't break later, when we fix CTE optimisation. I've asked for just that but never got anywhere, there's a lot of hand-waving about it being a "feature" to have this limitation instead. /frustrated.

Comment: It was a real irritation to me when I stumbled on it, coming from an Oracle background. CTE's are much more useful than subqueries for tidying up code, and I hate to be forced to write untidy code because a predicate can't be pushed into a CTE.