# PostgreSQL - CTE slowing the query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I have a concern regarding the use of multiple `WITH` clauses in a query because 
in some condition, it is slowing down the performance of the query like the below example,

So first `WITH` clause taking the **0.345 sec** to fetch the **98948** records and second `WITH` clause taking the **13 sec** to fetch the **68199** records even its less record as compare to first one so the only difference is that we have used the aggregate function in the second `WITH` clause to calculate the sum of charges.

Can anybody please help us to understand why the second query taking too much time.

**1.This clause taking the 0.318 sec to fetch the 98948 record,**

```
WITH delinquency_lease_details AS (
    SELECT
        dp.cid,
        dp.id AS delinquency_policy_id,
        p.id,
        dp.threshold_amount,
        dp.small_balance_amount,
        dp.delinquency_threshold_type_id,
        cl.id,
        cl.primary_customer_id AS customer_id,
        cl.lease_status_type_id,
        cl.occupancy_type_id,
        COALESCE( cl.building_name || ' - ' || cl.unit_number_cache, cl.building_name, cl.unit_number_cache ) AS unit_number, func_format_customer_name ( cl.name_first, cl.name_last, cl.company_name ) customer_name, cl.property_name, TZ.time_zone_name AS property_timezone
FROM
    cached_leases cl
    JOIN lease_details ld ON ( ld.cid = cl.cid AND ld.lease_id = cl.id )
    JOIN delinquency_policies dp ON ( dp.cid = ld.cid AND ld.delinquency_policy_id = dp.id )
    JOIN properties p ON ( p.cid = lp.cid AND p.id = lp.property_id )
    JOIN time_zones TZ ON ( TZ.id = p.time_zone_id )
WHERE
    cl.cid = 1111
    AND cl.lease_status_type_id IN ( 4, 5 )
    AND cl.occupancy_type_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11 )
    AND cl.termination_list_type_id IS NULL
)

SELECT * FROM delinquency_lease_details;
```

**2. This clause taking the 13 sec to fetch the 68199 records and if I just run the query without `WITH` clause then it is taking 0.564 seconds,**

```
WITH delinquent_balance AS (
    SELECT
        dld.cid,
        dld.id,
        min( c.post_date ) AS min_post_date,
        sum( c.transaction_amount_due ) AS delinquent_amount
    FROM
        cached_leases dld
        JOIN charges at ON ( at.cid = dld.cid AND at.lease_id = dld.id AND c.is_temporary = FALSE AND c.is_deleted = FALSE )
        JOIN charge_codes cc ON ( c.ar_code_id = cc.id AND c.cid = cc.cid AND cc.ledger_filter_id = 27 )
    WHERE
        dld.cid = 1111
        AND ( ( c.transaction_amount_due > 0 AND c.post_date < CURRENT_DATE ) OR c.transaction_amount_due < 0 )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            select
                1
            from
                repayment_charges
            WHERE
                cid = c.cid
                AND property_id = c.property_id
                AND charge_id = c.id
                AND is_active = true
        )
    GROUP BY
        dld.cid,
        dld.id

) select * from delinquent_balance;
```

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844732/8006404), the `WITH` clause is the optimization barrier for Postgres database so it's really a cause then what we should use in place of `WITH` clause for complex queries because I have used the 10 WITH clauses in query and it is slowing down the performance of the query but out of that I have given two clauses only to get the some conclusion because the second clause taking more time as compared to another one.

Comment: Have you tried running explain on both queries (both with and without the CTEs)?  I would have guessed that the CTE would not be any different than inlining the query directly, but apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: Postgres persists CTE's which may account for the difference.

Comment: Have you tried using temporary tables?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Yes I tried for and first WITH clause taking same with and without but the second taking near about 13 sec using WITH and without WITH 0.545 sec as I mentioned.

Comment: @AbhishekGinani Yes, I was thinking same to use the temporary tables with indexing because if we just create temp table without indexing then it is taking time.

Comment: The queries are different, but in both queries the actual query is completely contained in the CTE. The final query only needs to do a sequential scan on the CTE's result. Rewriting the two queries into a form without a CTE will probably result in similar timings.

Comment: It is impossible to give an answer without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.